# Number of watchers in Angular

Tags: angularjs, batarang

I am bit confused on the number of watchers in a angular code.I have a extremely simple Angular Controller with just one variable.

```
function SomeClass($scope,$sce) {
        $scope.Data = "";
    }
```

This variable is binded to a textbox and also displayed as expression.

```
<input type="text" name="name" value="" ng-model="Data" />
{{Data}}
```

When i profile in Batarang tool i see 3 watchers for {{Data}} , So first question should not it be just one watcher. One expression one watcher to evaluate. I do understand one watcher triggers other watchers but 3 looks a weird number.

And  is the second watcher for the textbox ng-model binding and why 2 watchers. Or is there something wrong with batarang

[image]

Comment: Its correct number..it should have 2 watchers, one for `{{Data}}` other for `ng-model`, you could find same thing inside `console.log($scope.$$watchers)` object